# How can I get the user inputs in angularjs and pass it from one modal to another? How controllers are connected in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to Javascript and Angular....and I am trying to change a code so that when the user click on a button, it shows a form to user to enter her/his name, then if they press submit button [Smilar to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DLve.png) , the result should be saved.

So I have a main controller and view (let's say its name is page), when the first button is clicked, a function will be called that make the form visible:

```
mainController.controller('Page', ['$scope','ModalService' ,
  function($scope,ModalService) {  

  $scope.clickHere = function () {
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: "angular/views/modals/myForm.html",
        controller:  "myFormCtrl"
    }).then(function(modal) {

        //it's a bootstrap element, use 'modal' to show it
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function(result) {
            if(result=='submit')
            {

            }
        });
    });        
}
```

and the form controller looks like this:

```
mainController.controller('myFormCtrl', ['$scope','close',
      function($scope,close) {

        $scope.test = angular.element(document.getElementById("username")).val()
        console.log($scope.test)

        //$scope.test = username.getText()
        $scope.close = function(result) {

            console.log($scope.test)
            close(result, 500);
        };

    }]);
```

Now I am very confused, I don't know how to pass the name of the user to the Page so I can use it for in other functions that I have...I want the name of the user to be passed when Submit is selected and nothing happens otherwise.

Just a node: All controllers and Models and HTML codes are connected...I see the form and I can click on submit...but I cannot save the result.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Use a service to store your business logic. Services are singletons that are imported into controllers so they can discuss and exchange data.

Comment: Thanks For your reply @JeremyThille ...There is no easy way to return value like other programming languages?

Comment: It's not a question of programming language. Controllers and services are part of the Angular framework's logic (which is made with Javascript, of course)

Comment: @JeremyThille so I see in the code there are a few service...but they have no inputs and nothing to return, how they are useful?
    var mainServices = angular.module('mainServices', []).
    .service('something', function () {
    return {}; })
Don't they need to have some variable at least?

Comment: This is way too broad to discuss on StackOverflow. If you don't know what services are and how to use Angular, I would suggest you to follow tutorials and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Information can be shared across controllers using services. You can create a variable in the ModalService, inject ModalService into the controller of the form and set that variable with the name entered by user. Then, you can access this variable in parent controller via already injected ModalService

Comment: Curious to know if this helped?